# Stop simple product images overriding main product gallery after clicking swatches

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.2, simple-product, swatches, gallery

I've upgraded from **2.1.9 to 2.2.3.** Now on a configurable product page when a swatch is selected the product page gallery **images get overridden** by the simple product image for each swatch.

This didn't used to happen and I can't find a way to stop this behaviour. I only want the configurable product images to show as in the past. I actually only have thumbnails associated with simple products to show at the checkout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By adding the following code to the theme's view.xml the image from the simple product is now added to the product gallery rather than replacing the one associated with the configurable product.

```
<vars module="Magento_ConfigurableProduct">
    <var name="gallery_switch_strategy">prepend</var>
</vars>
```

Comment: I would still like to find a way to stop the simple product image appearing in the configurable product gallery altogether? I don't need separate photos for each simple product. I only have thumbnails associated with the simple products but they are being shown in the gallery when the swatch image is clicked on. Even though Hide from Product Page is checked.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to alter the behavior of how the gallery switching happens, I think the function you are looking for is in

> vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js

called `processUpdateBaseImage`

This is completely untested, but you can create a mixin and change that function's behavior, something like:

Namespace/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js -

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer': {
                'Namespace_Module/js/swatch-renderer-mixin': true
            },
        }
    }
};
```

Namespace/Module/view/web/js/swatch-renderer-mixin.js -

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        /**
         * Update [gallery-placeholder] or [product-image-photo]
         * @param {Array} images
         * @param {jQuery} context
         * @param {Boolean} isInProductView
         * @param {Object} gallery
         */
        processUpdateBaseImage: function (images, context, isInProductView, gallery) {
            var justAnImage = images[0],
                initialImages = this.options.mediaGalleryInitial,
                imagesToUpdate,
                isInitial;

            if (isInProductView) {
                imagesToUpdate = images.length ? this._setImageType($.extend(true, [], images)) : [];
                isInitial = _.isEqual(imagesToUpdate, initialImages);

                if (this.options.gallerySwitchStrategy === 'prepend' && !isInitial) {
                    imagesToUpdate = imagesToUpdate.concat(initialImages);
                }

                imagesToUpdate = this._setImageIndex(imagesToUpdate);
                gallery.updateData(imagesToUpdate);

                if (isInitial) {
                    $(this.options.mediaGallerySelector).AddFotoramaVideoEvents();
                } else {
                    $(this.options.mediaGallerySelector).AddFotoramaVideoEvents({
                        selectedOption: this.getProduct(),
                        dataMergeStrategy: this.options.gallerySwitchStrategy
                    });
                }

                gallery.first();

            } else if (justAnImage && justAnImage.img) {
                context.find('.product-image-photo').attr('src', justAnImage.img);
            }
        }
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    }
});
```